# How to say "fuckers" in Russian

Tags: одним-словом, мат

I'm writing a story with a Russian soldier, and I usually put her swearing into Russian so as to not be immediately offensive to English readers.

So, the word that I'm needing is *"fuckers"*. To put it in context, the line is: *"How does it feel to burn—just like all the people on all the planets you [fuckers] glassed?"*

What's the right word that I would need for this?

Comment: Looks like your story is set in a quite distant future and you want a FEMALE RUSSIAN SOLDIER to do the swearing for you so the 'good guys' don't have to. I've had enough of this in Hollywood movies. I'm not answering this question.

Comment: In my personal opinion, using a kind of [nadsat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nadsat) is not a good idea at all. Read a couple of pages from "Clockwork orange" to get an impression how readers would struggle through the text with inserted foreign words.

Comment: Do you speak Russian at least at the most basic level? because of none at all - then find some foreign language student with at least basic exposure to Russian. Or better something like Yul Brinner. Otherwise you would make veeery stupid mash-up of wrong Russian-sounding words.

Comment: @SergeySlepov you think about canonical female heroes. But look at persons like Savchenko. In peaceful times she was noone's riff-raff. Today she is Ukrainian terrorists hero. But put her into ww2 context - and she easily would become red army daredevil. So, while such a heroine would be taken with huge grain of salt, there is some room for it.

Comment: Are you asking how to translate the phrase into Russian? Or what Russian obscenity to put into the English phrase so as not to offend the English speaking readers? The latter question is off-topic on this site, I'm afraid, it'd better be asked on English.SE.

Comment: Actually @SergeySlepov, she is one of the good guys; actually one of my favorite characters in the story. It's a Halo story, and it's set after the Covenant - aliens - glassed a portion of Earth extending (in my story) all the way up to the North Pole--including areas of Russia. So she's very angry at the loss of her home and family to them.

Comment: @Abakan, I do put the Russian into English letters. For example I would write "девушка" as "devushka".

Comment: @Arioch, yes I am in the process of learning Russian. I know a fair amount, but I'm not fluent yet. I am learning through Rosetta Stone and Duolingo.

Comment: @Allen R. You may also want to explore whether a Russian soldier is more likely to say another expletive instead of *"fuckers"*. If you search on Google then *"уёбки"* is used 342,000 times; *"суки"* [bitches] is used 6,770,000 times; *"бляди"* [whores] is used 6,280,000 times. Different language cultivates different preferences for name calling.

Comment: Given present status of Russian language, it would be very likely that a pejorative gay word (which I would not mention here) would be used, and not many of the options already mentioned.

Comment: @Vitaly, "бляди" would actually work best in terms of speaking it out. Saying "...on all the planets you _blyadi_ glassed..." works way better than "...you _uyobki_..." - so thanks!

Comment: @AllenR You're writing in English for English-speaking audience and you're putting Russian words in the mouth of your otherwise English-speaking character. This is a literary device (no real people, even native Russian speakers who speak English poorly, talk this way), and not the best one out there. It's not a good idea to use that at all, but if you still have to, you should be concerned about how familiar with the expletive your audience is rather than its actual Russian meaning. Since you're writing for video gamers, "cyka blyad" would be probably you best (or rather least bad) shot.

Comment: @AllenR in Russian, a Russian would have said *гондоны* ("condoms"), *пидоры* ("faggots") or *уёбки* indeed, but that would be probably weird, not familiar, or even more insulting than an English expletive to your audience. So if I was forced to use this literary device, my only criteria would have been what share of the audience are familiar with the word in question.

Comment: бляди does not have connotation of cruelty (but more of treason/corruption), so the best would be uyobki or mudaki

Comment: That's good insight, @Anixx ! Would "mudaki" would convey the sense of planet-wide genocide that I'm referencing in the story?

Comment: Yes. Very much.

Answer (score 8):

"*Твари*" or "*мрази*" are the best words I can think of. Neither of them are truly obscene, though. The genitalia-derived obscenities offered in other answers have something comical about them, not something you would seriously call a strong and dangerous enemy who has glassed so many planets (unless you want to portray the situation with a degree of humor). When you call a person something like "*уёбок*" or "*долбоёб*", the nuance is that he is a somewhat inept person, doing his bad things at least partially out of stupidity.

Can't refrain from offering my very valuable opinion on the matter in general. I am a native speaker of Russian with semi-decent English. I also speak enough Japanese to get by. I like cursing (yes, in all three languages) and often do, but can't remember ever using a curse from a language foreign to the one I am speaking at the moment. That would just feel sooo awkward. The grammar is different, the phrase composition is usually different enough so that there's simply no good place to insert a foreign curse into. The way you [are trying to] pronounce "corresponding" sounds in different languages is also different, should I pronounce it like I would in English, e. g. "moo duck", or the plain Russian "мудак" will do? Switching takes enough time and mental effort to kick you out of the flow. The closest thing to your example I can imaging myself saying is something like: "What are you doing, you... you... *[struggling to remember the word "faggot" for a second and failing]*... *пидор*!"

And no, "Clockwork Orange" is not a good counter-example, what's described there is a sub-cultural phenomenon of taking a very limited subset of foreign words and adapting them to English grammar and phonetics.

Answer (score 7):

**It's `уёбок` or `ушлёпок`.**

I'd go with `уёбки` (singular [`уёбок`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D1%91%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA)) or `уебаны` (singular [`уебан`](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD)) - this is exactly something like fuckers.

It's comparably more neutral than `ебанат`, there's also word [`долбоёб`](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%91%D0%B1) but it's more like `stupid fucker`.

There's also [`мудила`](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0) but it's more like stupid asshole or douchebag.

So, "уёбок", definitely "уёбок" :)

Or if want to use something similar but less abusive (because the root `ебать` from which `уёбок` is derived is highly offensive and not acceptable in the majority of cases, **it's not like `fuck`** in that sense) - use [`ушлёпок`](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA) - this is exactly the same but you can use it, say, on TV without the risk of being ostracized.

Comment: Shahen, isn't there another word that looks something like уёбице(?)

Comment: @CocoPop - `уёбище` (`щ`, not `ц`) is yet another form of `уёбок`

Comment: @shabunc, "уёбки" looks to be exactly what I'm looking for in this instance. Would it be properly Anglicized as "uyobki" or just "uebki"? I use English letters in my story for readers who don't know the azbuka.

Comment: @AllenR. "uyobki" is what your need )

Comment: But those are VERY tabooed words. Maybe "отморозки" might fit in too. Meaning people "frozen their brains to the point they have no more", absolutely detached from humanity

Comment: @Arioch - "отморозки" are not stupid, "отмороженность" implies having no moral limitations (just like you've said) - it's definitely not fuckers.

Comment: I did not say it means stupid or like that

Comment: The proposed translation is a very good match for English *"fuckers",* exactly as requested by @Allen R.  But IMHO, a native speaker would use one of more popular/common expletives. *"Uyobki"* is used rather infrequently compared to other swear words.

Comment: Guys... I know these words are "taboo" and seen as social bad. That's what I'm looking for, in this instance.

Answer (score 6):

The people above try to get a rough translation, while in this situation I would look for an equivalent, not exact translation

I would go with one of the following

somewhat mild variations

- **Сволочи** (literally: any person causing a lot of trouble for no good reason)
- **Гады** (similar meaning in modern language, but was used to mean "snakes and their biological relatives")
- **Ублюдки** (literally: bastards, but derogatory as well)
- **Идиоты** (just idiots, fitting if the effect was unexpected)
- **Нелюди** (literally: non-people, used for people with completely screwed or absent moral compass)

obscene variants

- **Мудаки** (derived from муды - balls. Male balls. May be used both for stupid and bitchy person)
- **Долбоёбы** (derived from ебать : to fuck. Mostly used for fantastic idiots)
- **Уебаны/Уёбки** (similar to above, but is well suited for people with very screwed morality as well)

Please, note: obscenities in russian are considered to be obscenities: they are 'beep'ed on tv and are not allowed in civil settings. Refined people never use them, and even unrefined people do not use them in formal settings. Very few people would use obscenities in formal settings, and this is not considered acceptable. A truly refined person should be able to make opponent cry from understanding of own low place in life without obscenities.

Answer (score 5):

I think "*суки*" would go good in this situation. It is plural of "[сука](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B)" which means "*female dog*" but also has a meaning "*bitch*" and can be applied not only to female persons.

Comment: или "твари" ( ~ beasts ), или "звери", или "черти" - вариантов море. Характер героини надо прорабатывать, надо написать ее подробную биографию до книги, а оптом сжечь. И уже тогда выбирать ей язык, с учетом ее "культурного прошлого"...

Comment: English "bitch" does mean "female dog" too, that is its main meaning.

Comment: English "bitch" has a somewhat different meaning from Russian "сука" as a "called name". "Сука" is perfectly suitable for a male (or unknown gender) party and more close to "bastard" in meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Just take explicit-language-aware translations of Hollywood war movies and look at situations what would suit you.

Two lists of movies and download link.

- https://oper.ru/trans/?pp - "proper translations"
- https://oper.ru/trans/?bi - "parody translations"
- http://subtitry.ru/subtitles/?translator=Goblin - subtitles downloading.

The first link gives you list of movies you might want to look into.
The second - the list of movies you definitely need to stay away from, in the context of this work.
The third - should let you download subtitles to the movies you selected and read them.

---

Then, still you would have to make her language consistent with her cultural background, with her past. Because expletives can be translated rather vague, and if you would pick different style, different semantic cloud expletives - it would sound chaotic and weird for her personality.

When Barry Longyear was writing a novel about blinded woman, he not only lived few weeks with eyes covered, he also allegedly wrote a full bio of that woman, that was scrapped later, but that provided all the details and nuances he needed in the published novel.

Comment: please update you answer or it would be turned into a comment - answer supposed to be self-sufficient, yours is not - links can change over time. Also, you are not providing answer at all.

Comment: if the comment would be able to hole this amount of content and formatting - I would make it a comment myself. But comments can handle neither. W.r.t. answer, the proper One True Translation would only be able to made after knowing full heroine's bio, including one before the plot, which we do not know. So my answer is answer, it is just a "fishing rod rather than fish" kind of answer.

Comment: This does bring a good proofreading point to mind. @shabunc (or any Mod), would I be able to link my story here, to make sure that the character's use of Russian is consistent and accurate?

Comment: Perhaps it really would make sense to find some russian fiction forum?..
Stretches a lot...

Comment: @AllenR. unfortunately proof-reading hardly can be an on-topic here, so yes, may be some russian ficion forum.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the context of your presumably fantastic novel, where the character is addressing an alien life form, I guess the best option would be **пидорасы** (lit. **homos**, or **faggots**).

But since you are writing about a female character, I think a recently developed feministic swearing **хуемрази** (**ед. ч. "хуемразь",** literally smth like 'dick-bastards' or 'dick-creatures') would do.

But, again, we don't know much about the races and sexes (if any) of her addressees--

Comment: The second is something new and is not widely used

Comment: @Dmitry So what? It's a sci-fi, after all.

Comment: I just wanted to say that the typical Russian soldier in this situation will use the first with much bigger probability than the second. But of course, it is always possible to find another soldier, who prefers the second.

Comment: @Dmitry With those post-feminist soldiers in a sci-fi world addressing an unknown race of unknown sex(es?) you can never know---

Comment: Уел ;) Не знаю, как это по-английски.

Comment: @Manjusri, if it helps the aliens being addressed are well-known by humanity, and this one in particular is male.

Comment: @Allen R Then I think ***хуемрази***  [pronounced *hooyemrahzi* / *hooyemruzzi*, Nom. Sg. ***хуемразь*** [hooyemrahz' / hooyemruzz']) would do fine; it's a nice feminist & lesbian  swearing used particularly against men, thnx to my third ex-wife for letting me know it :-D I don't vouch for the accuracy of the transliteration, though :-D

Comment: @Allen R; but, again, that depends on what type of a 'belligerant damsel' the soldier is; if she is more pro-feminist, then she would use the swearing 'hooyemrazi', but if she is more 'soldier Jane'-type, then she would most likely call the aliens 'piddorahssy'.